# Error when generating PDF document having an image integrated

Tags: image, templates, pdf, orbeon

When I generate a PDF from Orbeon that will get an image (with this url: `oxf:/forms/orbeon/dmv-14/images/user_32.png`) and add it to the PDF, il works fine.

But when orbeon is embedded in a web application, the PDF document is not generated and we have the following error in the log. Do you have an idea how to resolve this?

```
An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 submission URL scheme not supported: null                                                                             Application Call Stack
```

and then in the stacktrace :

```
Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.OXFException                                                                         |--|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Connection                     |connect                       |Connection.scala              | 199|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Connection                     |connect                       |Connection.scala              | 202|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pdf.PDFTemplateProcessor  |image$lzycompute$1            |PDFTemplateProcessor.scala    | 350|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pdf.PDFTemplateProcessor  |org$orbeon$oxf$processor$pdf$P|PDFTemplateProcessor.scala    | 317|
|sor.pdf.PDFTemplateProcessor$$anonfun$handleImage$1|apply                         |PDFTemplateProcessor.scala    | 371|
|sor.pdf.PDFTemplateProcessor$$anonfun$handleImage$1|apply                         |PDFTemplateProcessor.scala    | 368|
|scala.Option                                       |foreach                       |Option.scala                  | 257|
```

### Edit:

@ebruchez
Below are more details about the problem: 
- a screenshot of the form which includes an image and one text :[image]
- a scrennshot of the PDF generated after click on "PDF" using PDF Template. This works fine with orbeon not embedded :
[image]

When Orbeon is embedded in a web application, the PDF Template is not generated and these are  screenshots of the form and the PDF template.[image][image]
This is the screenshot of Mapping PDF :[image]

NOTE : I used the PDF with the processor XHTMLToPDF (without Template) , it works normally.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lebki, I've asked Erik to follow-up with you on this, as he knows more about PDF generation than I do. I imagine he will be following-up here shortly.

Comment: Ok i will wait his response.Thanks.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this but it works so far. Are you using the [Form Runner Java Embedding API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/link-embed/java-api.html)? If not how do you embed? Do you have a form you can share? Which version of Orbeon Forms?

Comment: Erik, yes i use the Form Runner Java Embedding Api in a  web application based on Spring Boot and Angular js .The version of Orbeon forms is 2016.2 (201608230022-PE). Also  in embedding,when i upload an image the progress bar was blocked without any error. I use to generate a PDF the  template pdf instead of the processor XHTMLToPDF.In mode embedding, the state of the request upload of image is in 'pending'.

Comment: Erik, I've added more details with screenshots about the problem. Thanks.